# codeacademy battleship project syntax error

Tags: python

i'm learning python through the codeacademy website.
Now i;m trying to code the battleship project,where i face a problem:
my code is:

```
import random

board = []

for x in range(0,5):
  board.append(["O"] * 5)

def print_board(board):
  for row in board:
    print " ".join(row)

print_board(board)

def random_row(board):
  return random.randint(0,len(board)-1)

def random_col(board):
    return random.randint(0,len(board[0])-1)

ship_row = random_row(board)
ship_col = random_col(board)
guess_row = input("Guess Row:")
guess_col = input("Guess Col:")

print ship_row
print ship_col

if (guess_row == ship_row and guess_col == ship_col):
    print "Congratulations! You sank my battleship!"
else:
    if((guess_row < 0) or (guess_row > (len(board) -1) or (guess_col < 0) or (guess_col> (len(board) -1)):
        print "Oops, that’s not even in the ocean."
    else:
        print "You missed my battleship!"
        guess_row = "X"
        guess_col = "X"
        print_board(board)
    if board[guess_row][guess_col] == "X":
        print "You guessed that one already."
```

but it returns this error:

```
    if((guess_row < 0) or (guess_row > (len(board) -1) or (guess_col < 0) or (guess_col> (len(board) -1)):
                                                                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can you help me with this situation?

thank in advance guys

Comment: Aside: it looks like you're mixing indentation styles.  Sometimes you use two spaces, and sometimes you use tabs.  [Use `python -tt your_program_name.py` to confirm this.]  This is going to get you into hard-to-debug trouble.  Use four-space tabs instead.

Comment: try this : `if((guess_row < 0) or (guess_row > (len(board)-1)) or (guess_col < 0) or (guess_col> (len(board)-1)))`

Comment: By the time Python counts whitespaces in a strange way,i think i'll have to use 4-spaces tabs instead of the spaces..thank you for the advice!

Comment: Is it just me that i think something goes wrong with the list dimensions?? When i run the script, it does not put X on the right row+column..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have nine opening but only seven closing parentheses.

I personally would remove most of them:

```
 if guess_row < 0 or guess_row >= len(board) or guess_col < 0 or guess_col >= len(board):
```

or, better still:

```
 if not (0 <= guess_row < len(board)) or not (0 <= guess_col < len(board)):
```

Here, the two pairs of parentheses after `not` are not necessary, but IMO improve readability. Feel free to drop them if you disagree.

There are some other issues with the code.

The following:

```
    guess_row = "X"
    guess_col = "X"
```

should probably read

```
    board[guess_row][guess_col] = "X"
```

Also the `if board[guess_row][guess_col] == "X":` check should be done either before or instead of setting `board[guess_row][guess_col]` to `"X"` for the current `guess_row` and `guess_col`.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `)` just before the colon (edit: you're missing another one too). Your line should be:

```
if((guess_row < 0) or (guess_row > (len(board) -1)) or (guess_col < 0) or (guess_col> (len(board) -1))):
```

Comment: Thank you,now it's fixed! also,i had to make guess_row = "X"
        guess_col = "X" like this>> board[guess_row][guess_col] == "X"

Comment: No,i just found this bug and mentioned it for the record!

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
if(guess_row < 0) or (guess_row > (len(board) -1)) or (guess_col < 0) or (guess_col> (len(board) -1)):
```